# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when adding data to NSMutable array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

Well i am parsing data from json and I add them dynamically to an array. If i add 12 data of them, its ok. But when I am going to add an 13th I get this error(no matter what is the 13th):

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Here is my code:

```
HomeView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeView : UIViewController{  
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;

@end
```

and my implementation file:

```
@implementation HomeView
@synthesize responseData;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

// convert to JSON
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
    NSString *parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data1"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data2"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data3"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data4"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data5"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data6"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];

   parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data7"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data8"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data9"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data10"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data11"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
    parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data12"];
    [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];

  // parsed_track=[res objectForKey:@"data13"]; //HERE COMES THE ERROR
   // [tracks_condition addObject:parsed_track];
```

}

I guess it is something with memory management but I cannot find out what.

Comment: That's not all of your code. You show your responseData property but don't use it, and the rest of it looks like a code chunk thrown in without context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is an object for key `@"data13"` maybe this key does not exists and returns `nil`. in that case you need to check for `nil` and decide do you want to add it or not. If you want to add it just add `[NSNull null]` instead as you have to use an object that inherits `NSObject`.

Edit: please try to make it in a for loop too and construct the string with `[NSString stringWithFormat.....]`

Comment: no, it exists. I have key until data 18 and everything I add more than 12 gets me that error.

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is because you are adding a `nil` object to the array, or the object has already been released by the time you add it to the array.

On another note, you can use a for loop for adding the objects to the array, rather than many lines of code:

```
for (NSUInteger idx = 1; idx <= [[res allKeys] count]; idx++) {

    if ([[[res allKeys] objectAtIndex:idx] rangeOfString:@"data"].location != NSNotFound)
        [tracks_condition addObject:[res objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data%d", idx]]];

}
```

or even better:

```
[self.questionInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([key rangeOfString:@"data"].location != NSNotFound && obj != nil) {

            [tracks_condition addObject:obj];

        }

        else {

            if ([tracks_condition count] >= 18) {
                *stop = YES;

            }                   
        }

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but adding in such way is not possible as I want only 18 datas out of 30 that are being fetched, and datas are not being stored in the same way my script prints them out.